# Expect: No such variable

Tags: linux, bash, debian, expect

I started using expect. I have a simple script. But I have a problem. I want to init a variable which has a $ an first character:

```
set mystring "$THIS_IS_MY_STRING%"
```

So I get an error, because expect expects a variable. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you just have to escape the `$`. So it should be `"\$THIS_IS_MY_STRING%"`.

Comment: Wow that was fast. And yes you are right :) I'm not familiar with linux/bash. Something to remind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape any special characters such as the dollar sign by proceeding them with a backslash, so your code becomes

```
set mystring "\$THIS_IS_MY_STRING%"
```